# Are banding numeric variables and dummy variables the same thing?

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable

So I am running a logistic regression analysis and my client wants me to see which variables are banded or not. But, in reading the original developer's code, they create dummy variables (assigning a 0 to a score above 650).

I assumed creating these dummy variables are different from creating banded variables. Are they the same thing?

FYI: I tried googling, but I couldn't find a source that talked about them in the same text.

Comment: What is a banded variable?

Comment: Banded variable - converting numeric variables to categorical. Dummy is assigning a 0 or 1 to a variable (ex . Credit score > 650 <- 0 as in dummy). I think of banded as this: (Credit score  650 <- High). I am not sure if my thinking is actually correct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization_of_continuous_features ?

Comment: Anyway, dummy variables are not the same as continuous variables turned categorical.

Comment: I think banding would be more like what the `cut()` function does. In reality I would see it like this: Dummy can be considered Banded if the only "Bands" or "Buckets" are groups 0 and 1.  Meanwhile a Banded variable can theoretically be named any number of things and can have any number of groups. These might be dummy in nature (i.e. a factor) or they could ordinal in nature, or other.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.